# Make a cell equal to a concatenation of its column and row headers in Excel

Tags: excel, cell, columnheader, rowheader

I have a (large) table with row and column headers of the following format:
[table with row and column headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDTY3.png)

I'd like to set the cells marked with 'x' to a concatenation of the column header and the row header, separated by a comma.
For example, cell B2 should be set to "c1_HEADER, r1_HEADER".

Is there a formula I can use to achieve this? At least by clicking the 'x' marked cells and applying the formula? I'd hate to take the manual route all the way :/.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with:

[image]

running this macro:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("B2").CurrentRegion
        If r.Value = "x" Then
            r.Value = r.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Value & "," & r.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

***Note:***

in this macro `Range("B2").CurrentRegion` represents the **block** of cells that we are looping through.  The variable `r` is a single-cell range that facilitates the loop.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I've never really used macros before, but I must say this was something beautiful. Thank you, good sir/ma'am.
For my further knowledge, however, could you explain the terms:

`Dim r As Range`; AND
`Range("B2").CurrentRegion` ?

Comment: @Shiv  See my ***Note***